# Openvpn connects but I cannot ping the gateway or access internet

Tags: openvpn

I have the following in my configuration file:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote xxxx.com 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
tls-version-min 1.2
verify-x509-name server_9UxxxVmX7i5 name
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
compress lz4
verb 3
```

The connection is properly established on Ubuntu 17.10 and the routing table looks like this

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    50     0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         10.111.48.1     0.0.0.0         UG    20600  0        0 wlo1
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     50     0        0 tun0
10.111.48.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1
10.111.48.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    600    0        0 wlo1
123.123.123.123  10.111.48.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlo1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlo1
```

The issue is I can ping myself, 10.8.0.2 but I cannot ping anything else (even the gateway) on the tun1 subnet. Virtually no access to the rest of the internet. Do you seen anything that I may be missing?

Comment: Check your OpenVPN's logs.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running into a routing issue here. You did not issue the `redirect-gateway` directive withing the configuration file. Hence you either get that pushed or you get a DHCP-address. It's possible that as soon you connect, the DHCP-gateway + interface takes precedence and you lose your VPN-connection because it tries to keep the vpn-connection up via the virtual interface. Try to NOT set a gateway-address, then your connection should work. If you have configured a firewall on your ubuntu server please also check the firewall-settings.

An alternative would be to use the `redirect-gateway` config option, then openvpn normally creates a host route for the VPN-endpoint in your local routing table to still go out via the - in your case `wlo1` - local interface.